# gridExtra::marrangeGrob set a subtitle

Tags: r, gridextra

I have a function that groups several plots in the same document, I use the gridExtra::marrangeGrob() function.  I want to put a title or subtitle just below the page number indication.

I get a strange behavior 
In a first one I get an error indicating that it does not find the subtitle variable. 
When I declare the subtitle variable outside the function declaration it puts me in the document this value there.

```
pl <- lapply(1:20, function(.x) qplot(1:10, rnorm(10),
                                      main=paste("plot", .x))+
               labs(x="", y="", title=""))

subtitle <- "b"

wrap_mg(lp = pl, name = "name.pdf", width = 400, height = 350,
        subtitle = "a") # if subtitle <- "b" is commented on I get a error:
 # Error in is.list(val) : object 'subtitle' not found 
# else in my document a get the value "b" 

#' @title Merge plot.
#' @description Merge plot from a list.
#' @param lp         list       - list of plot.
#' @param name       character  - name file.
#' @param width      numeric    - Width.
#' @param height     numeric    - Height.
#' @param subtitle   character  - subtitle of document.
#' @export
#'
wrap_mg <- function(lp, name, width, height,
                      subtitle){

  lay <- rbind(c(1,2,3),                                               
               c(4,5,6),
               c(7,8,9))

    ml <- gridExtra::marrangeGrob(lp, nrow=3, ncol=3,
                                  layout_matrix=lay,
                                  left="left",
                                  bottom="bot",
                                  top = quote(paste("page", g, "of",
                                                    npages, "\n", "\n",
                                                    subtitle))
    )

    ggsave(plot = ml, filename = name, dpi = 400, device = "pdf",
           width = width, height = height,
           units = c("mm"),limitsize = FALSE)    

}
```

Comment: how about using `bquote` e.g. `top = bquote(paste("page", g, "of", npages, "\n", "\n", .(subtitle)))`